# android-aam project run error

Tags: java, android, opencv

Are you the author of https://github.com/SolessChong/android-aam, I came across a problem as follows: the code compiles, but it doesn't run correctly.

Here is the error:

> OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The total matrix size does not fit to "size_t" type) in void cv::setSize(cv::Mat&, int, int const*, const size_t*, bool), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 126
>   from org.opencv.samples.facedetect.

I don't know what is going on. Please help me!

Comment: Thanks for editing.I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this error too. Change 3 file paths in the construction of TrackerWrapper in jni folder: "/storage/sdcard1/face2.tracker" to "/mnt/sdcard/FaceDetection/face2.tracker"(your real file path in your android phone). You also need to copy these files(could be found in jni/model) at phone with the same position. Then, recomplie jni and it can run.